# Definition of adsorption

Tags: electrolysis, adsorption

Wikepdia defines adsorption

> Adsorption is the adhesion of atoms, ions or molecules from a gas, liquid or dissolved solid to a surface

Does this make, a cation getting reduced and attaching to the surface of an electrode during electrolysis, an example of adsorption? It seems to satsify the above definiton. However, no matter what I search, I never see this as an example of adsorption.

Comment: There must be countless articles on reduction of adsorbed species on electrodes. Adsorption "typically" means that there is NO chemical reaction. Since you also want to adsorb and then do an electrochemical reduction, these are two distinct steps. Any definition of any term cannot encompass all examples in the world. Definitions are limited and man-made.

Comment: Yup, that would be adsorption. If it's forming a specific bond to the surface, that would be chemisorption; if it relies on intermolecular forces (e.g., ion-ion, London dispersion forces, etc.) it would be physisorption. Found some papers for reference. > https://doi.org/10.1039/D1SE01760H > https://doi.org/10.1002/elsa.202100183 > https://doi.org/10.1021/jp500425g

Comment: Yes, adsorption is one step on the electrode, the next step will be electroreduction. Adsorption's definition does not include electrochemical reduction as the OP is thinking.